# Multiple Email for single id with no duplicate

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

> i have a table register in this there are 2 columns email and id
>
> in this a id can have multiple email but it can't be duplicate  how to
>   solve it
>
> pls help i am new to asp.net

```
>  Public Shared Function checkvendemail(ByVal p_vendid As String, ByVal
> p_email As String) As Boolean
>             Dim CP As String
>             Using db As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.WSMplannet)
>                 db.Open()
>                 Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT 1 FROM Registration where email='" + p_email + "'", db)
>                     CP = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
>                     If String.IsNullOrEmpty(CP) Then CP = "N"
>                 End Using
>                 db.Close()
>             End Using
>             Return (CP.ToUpper = "Y")
>         End Function



 If Not (PRC.DTO.PRCContractor.Queries.checkvendemail(txtVendorID.Text, txtEmailAddress.Text)) Then
            litMessage.Text = "<a style=""font-weight: normal; color: red"">Email aready Registered .</a>"
            Exit Sub
        End If
```

Comment: what's the problem with your code?

Comment: i am getting1 email id for a single Id

Comment: i want multiple email id for single id with no duplicate

Comment: so what's happening to your code right now? it's allowing duplicate or causing an error?

Comment: yes.................

Comment: **Hint** : Use `SqlDataReader` to find whether `p_email` is already there in the table. If `sqldatareader.Read()` don't insert else insert.

Comment: yes what? it's allowing duplicate or causing an error?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the select... Your selecting 1... Also use parameters...

```
 SELECT 1 FROM...
```

Try `COUNT`

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
```

Then check your condition. Make CP an integer then check the CP...

For example

```
 If CP > 0 Then Return True Else Return False
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Public Shared Function checkvendemail(ByVal p_vendid As String, ByVal p_email As String) As Boolean
    Dim CP As String
        Using db As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.WSMplannet)
            db.Open()
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT 1 FROM Registration where UPPER(email) = '" + p_email.ToUpper() + "' AND id = " + p_vendid, db)
                CP = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(CP) Then CP = "N"
            End Using
            db.Close()
        End Using
    Return (CP.ToUpper = "Y")
End Function
```

It seems you're not using `p_vendid` parameter which seems to be the id for your Registration table.